# Adding HTML button to handle incrementation over element within a from within a looping array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

4I'm currently working on a HTML code for a presentation that changes image based on a javascript array.

I managed to incorporate a looping code from a friend into my code, but I don't understand how to only make the image change once.

At the moment, it works that the javascript loops the items in the array to display different images, but I'd like it to work that it only changes once, based on a button click.

I'd like to keep my array if possible.
Here's the code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var banners = ["banner1.png", "banner2.png", "banner3.png"
      "banner4.png"
    ];
    var bnrCntr = 0;
    var timer;

    function banCycle() {
      if (++bnrCntr == 4)
        bnrCntr = 0;

      timer = setTimeout("banCycle()", 4000);
    }

    function stopCycle() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="bannerad1.png" name="banner" width=110 height=200>

  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Cycle" name="Cycle" onclick="banCycle()">
    <input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" onclick="stopCycle()">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT-
Just to clarify, I'm limited to pure javascript/HTML, and therefore I cannot use JSQuery.

Comment: remove `timer = setTimeout("banCycle()",1000);`?

Comment: Sounds like you want a button to advance to the next image? And doesn't cycle through the remainder of the array?

Comment: @Fabricator It didn't work, and anyway, I'm looking for it to work on a button click, removing the timeout for the loop is still going to make it loop.

Comment: @EnigmaRM Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event in jquery. It would trigger the click event only once.

```
<script>
  $().ready(function(){
    var banners = ["banner1.png","banner2.png","banner3.png""banner4.png"];
    var bnrCntr = 0;
    var timer;
    $('input:button[name=Cycle]').one("click",function()
    {
      if(++bnrCntr == 4)
      bnrCntr = 0;

      document.images.banner.src = banners[bnrCntr];

      timer = setTimeout("banCycle()",1000);
    });

    $('input:button[name=Stop]').one("click",function()
    {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    });
});
    </script>
```

For a non jquery ( pure javascript ), just do a "return false". It would prevent further processing.

```
var banners = ["banner1.png","banner2.png","banner3.png""banner4.png"];
var bnrCntr = 0;
var timer;
var executedBanCycle = false;
var executedStopCycle = false;

function banCycle(e)
{
  if(executedBanCycle)
      return false;

  executedBanCycle = true;
  alert("Execute BanCyle");
  if(++bnrCntr == 4)
  bnrCntr = 0;

  document.images.banner.src = banners[bnrCntr];

  timer = setTimeout("banCycle()",1000);       

}

function stopCycle(e)
{
    if(executedStopCycle)
       return false;  
  executedStopCycle = true;
  alert("Execute stopCyle");
   clearTimeout(timer);

}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/f5xn7zhk/

Comment: That sounds great! However, I'm currently limited to pure javascript/HTML coding.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea can be seen here in this [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/e3wvt29b/)

**HTML**

```
<img id="banner" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<button onclick="next()">
  Next Image
</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var banners = ["http://placehold.it/350x150", "http://placehold.it/400x200", "http://placehold.it/300x100"]
var counter = 1;

function next() {
  if (counter >= banners.length){
    counter=0;
  }
  document.images.banner.src = banners[counter];
  counter++;
}
```

What you want to do is remove all of your cycle stuff. You can keep your Counter (what you have named `bnrCntr`). All you have to do is increment the counter by one each time the button is clicked.

By this logic, it would also be very easy to implement a "back" button that decrements the counter